# MPMoviePlayer - black screen - iOS 5 - no video playing

Tags: ios, media-player, mpmovieplayercontroller

In iOS 4 this Code worked to play a movie:

```
-(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testbild1" ofType:@"m4v"]];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    UIView *testview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];

    [testview addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [self.view addSubview:testview];
    //[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    //[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}  

- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification  
{  
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification object];  
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self  
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
                                                  object:moviePlayerController];  

    [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];  
    //[moviePlayerController release];  
}
```

Now, I only get a blackscreen. No controls, nothing. Video path is correct, I tested that. If I add just a white Subview by button click, it works. So the method is called.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have solved the issue by putting in the .h file

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
```

iOS 5 with ARC works differently than iOS 4.

The .m file must be:

```
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
```

Comment: I did the same (yet in an other project) where I put it this way intentionally and it worked perfectly. So I think this is it. Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: Can this work with PhoneGap? I'm not sure how/where to implement the fix using that framework

Comment: WTF. Made the same mistake in another project again and this one was the solution __AGAIN__ ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are on iOS 5.0 or 5.1, check your moviePlyer has a setting like below.

`[moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];`

If so, when you set `[moviePlayer setFullScreen:YES animated:YES];`
then MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification notification will be called instead of being called MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification or MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification